# Update string to Date object in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm working on mongodb and node.js and i came a across a scenario.

I'm bulk inserting data around 200 million record. In those there are some fields that are saved as string but actually are date.

Is there any way where I can do something like

```
db.collection.update({}, {$set: {dateField: new Date(dateField)}}, { multi: true })
```

Where date is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With a Modern MongoDB from version 4.2 or greater, you can actually do this in a single statement:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  {},
  [{ "$set": { "dateField": { "$toDate": "$dateField" } }}]
);
```

This relies on a new feature implemented at that version which allows "aggregation expressions" to be used within a statement which can indeed access the existing values of a document and use them to produce new output.

In this case the [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/) is used to "merge" new content with the existing document and the [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) handles the transformation.

---

### Old Answer

There is currently no feature in MongoDB that allows you to access the content of *another field* in an update operation. The only thing that you can do in any language for is iterate the results:

```
db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(doc) { 
    db.collection.update(
        { "_id": doc._id }, 
        {"$set": { "dateField": new Date(doc.dateField) }}
    );
});
```

Now, you *could* run that on the server using [`db.eval()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) **but beware** as there are many dangers to this as documented, and it is likely to have a large impact on a production system.

Failing that your other options are based on getting your **update** to run as close as possible (in network terms) to the database.

Also on your last writings it appears that your dates were not all in the format you mentioned here, but some entries had only one digit in the month or day. So you will have to deal with that as well if you have not already.

Comment: The first syntax need one more curly brace; `db.collection.updateMany({}, [{ "$set": { "dateField": { "$toDate": "$dateField" }}}]);`

Comment: is first option valid? $toDate is aggregation pipeline operator, not update operator

Comment: Note that the []-bulk operation around $set is vital here as without it the field is just set to the literal object

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants a mongoose version its pretty straight forward-

```
await FeeLog.updateMany({}, [{ "$set": { "<fieldname>": { "$toDate": "$fieldname" }}}]);
```