# MongoDB nested filters application

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have data in mongodb with multiple fields, I am trying to filter data on basis of a field named create_date and then trying to fetch totalrecordscount along with further filtering the data. Following is the data structure:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("62a886a76034628f8028e8dc"),
    "create_time" : "18:53:01",
    "close_date" : "2022-05-09",
    "close_time" : "13:34:43",
    "country_code" : "US",
    "closed_case" : 1,
    "resolution_days" : 8,
    "status_code" : "5",
    "state_code" : "1",
    "issue_resolved_flag" : "Yes",
    "incident_created_by" : "09D4A6BB-C51E-EB11-A813-000D3A58F938",
    "incident_modified_by" : "A3CBC776-DF3C-E711-810B-E0071B7284D1",
    "modifiedon" : "2022-05-09 13:34:46.0",
    "row_insertion_dttm" : "2022-06-14 02:58:21.202",
    "data_source_category" : "CASE",
    "resolution_duration_minutes" : 5060,
    "create_date" : "2022-05-01",
    "repeat_case_different_issue7_day" : 0,
    "repeat_case_same_issue_7day" : 0,
    "scr_7day" : 1,
    "ocr_7day" : 0,
    "csat_status" : "no"
```

I am able to aggregate the data on basis of create date and fetch the totalrecordscount for a particular date using following command :

```
country_code:1    
    }},
    {
        $match:{create_date:{$gt:"2022-06-01"}}
    },
    {$group:{ _id: {datebasis: "$create_date"},
    TotalRecordscount: { $sum: 1 },
   }
  },
  
  ])
```

The output is: {

```
    "_id" : {
    "datebasis" : "2022-06-17"
    },
    "TotalRecordscount" : 13254.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "datebasis" : "2022-06-14"
    },
    "TotalRecordscount" : 16688.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "datebasis" : "2022-06-09"
    },
    "TotalRecordscount" : 15478.0
}
```

But my ask is to further group the data to get the number of records on a particular date for fields like "scr_7day" equals to 0 or "resolution_duration_minutes" < 1440.
Can you help me in achieving this?

Comment: Are you storing the those dates as Date or string type in the collection? And comparing date with string `$gt: "2022-06-01"` is incorrect too.

Comment: actually the date field data is coming as string from the source, I also need to change the date format from string to date but that will be done later or do you want the date conversion to be done right away?

Comment: Hi @yong-shun you were right the first query, I tried converting the strings to date as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034195/update-string-to-date-object-in-mongodb but getting error Error: Failed to execute script.

Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators 
Details:
DBCollection.prototype.updateMany@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:625:1
@(shell):1:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you solve the date string logic as mentioned in the comment, my answer just focuses on your question.

You can work with `$count` and `$cond` operators to calculate the documents by condition.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        datebasis: "$create_date"
      },
      TotalRecordscount: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      scr_7dayIsZero: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $eq: [
                "$scr_7day",
                0
              ]
            },
            then: 1,
            else: 0
          }
        }
      },
      resolution_duration_minutesLessThan1440: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: {
            if: {
              $lt: [
                "$resolution_duration_minutes",
                1440
              ]
            },
            then: 1,
            else: 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NH73IY1NOut)

Comment: perfect!! this get the things done. Thank you so much for your time and effort.