# Cannot Update string to Date object in mongodb 4.2

Tags: mongodb, string-conversion

I have a string field which consists of date, I am trying to run following command mentioned in [Update string to Date object in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034195/update-string-to-date-object-in-mongodb)

```
db.getCollection('rft').updateMany(
  {},[{ "$set": { "createdate": { "$toDate": "$create_date" } }}]
);
```

Getting an error:
Error: Failed to execute script.

Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators
Details:
DBCollection.prototype.updateMany@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:625:1
@(shell):1:1

Can someone please help in updating the records to get new field with date time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems to work as expected , check [playgroud](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zd9d-VY2IbJ) unless something different is expected ...

Comment: For some reason the above command updateMany did not work rather update along with multi:true worked, following is the command for anyone's reference:db.collection.update({},[{"$set": {"createdate": {"$toDate": "$create_date"}}}],{multi: true})